# Is this process log normally distributed?

Tags: stochastic-processes, lognormal

I came across a question that I guess $P$ is lognormally distributed.

[image]

where $y_n$ is log-normally distributed.

Am I right on the guessing?

Here is the full solution if interested.( my guessing comes from the last two equations)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m sorry to say you’re not correct in your conclusion.  The basic problem is that in the second to last equation $$dP/P=D^*\sigma_y y_n dW_t$$ the $D^* $ is not constant but is a function of $y_n$ and therefore of $P$. Also you have a $y_n$ present which also is a function of $P$.  Hence $dP/P$ is not constant and therefore P is not in general lognormal.

Interestingly there is a case where $P$ is indeed lognormal if $y_n$ is. Consider the case of a perpetual bond with level coupons C where n is infinite. Then you can show from the first equation that the price $ P=C/y$.   Hence $dP=-Cdy/y^2$ and $dP/P= -dy/y$.  Then lognormality of $y$ implies lognormality of $P$.  But for all other cases it is not true.

Comment: thank you for clarifying  :)